# Change sha1 hash of files

Tags: hash, sha1

Lets say I have two files with two different sha1 hashes. Is there a way to change the hash of one file to the hash from the other file so they both have the same hash value?

The two files have different values in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Either:

- Change the content of the file so the two files are identical *or*
- Find another set of data (you'll probably have to brute force search this so it would take a lot of computing power) which happens to hash to the same value

You can't change the hash without changing the content of the file. The hash is just what you get after doing some calculations on the content of the file.

Comment: Since the files cant have identical content I will try the bruteforce option.